# Accessing individual elements from arrays formed in nested for loops

Tags: matlab

So I have numerous loops nested within one another and now want to access separate elements of each array for the final equation. Below is the code I have so far.

```
 for val = 1: xMid_p-1
      eapDia_p = diaArray_p(1,val);
      baseDia_p = diaArray_p(1,end);
      curDiaArray_p = linspace(eapDia_p, baseDia_p, xMid_p-1);
      curRadArray_p = curDiaArray_p/2;
      maxRad = max(curRadArray_p);

     for val = 1 : xMid_p-1
          ln(1,val) = maxRad(:) - curRadArray_p(val);

          for val =  1 : xMid_p - 2
               lnM(1,val) = maxRad(:) - curRadArray_p(val);

          end

      end 

      lnCubed(1,:) = ln.^3
      lnMCubed(1,:) = lnM.^3

end
```

What I am to do is subtract the first element of the array lnMCubed from the second element in lnCubed and so forth. Please see below:

```
  lnCubed =
     0    0.1    0.2    0.3    0.4    0.5    0.6   
  lnMCubed =
     0    0.1    0.2    0.3    0.4    0.5
```

i.e. I was to do 0.1 - 0, 0.2 - 0.1, 0.3 - 0.2, 0.4- 0.3, 0.5 - 0.4, 0.6 - 0.5

But I can't seem to structure the loops correctly

Comment: This - `lnCubed(2:end) - lnMCubed`?

Comment: Try this then - `lnCubed(1,2:end) - lnMCubed(1,:)`